# User-defined deduction guide for std types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, clang++, ctad

For some reason there is still lack of expected [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for `std::initializer_list` in [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55205176/3240681):

```
std::initializer_list l{1,2,3}; // error in clang
```

Adding a user-defined guide like the following can [fix the issue](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IOSwWNKyzuRNFmNf):

```
namespace std {
    template<class T> 
    initializer_list(const initializer_list<T>&) -> initializer_list<T>; 
}
```

But is it allowed to add a user-defined guide for CTAD for `std::` types?

Comment: Last time I checked, I got the impression that Clang is correct here, and `std::initializer_list l{1,2,3}; ` is not supposed to compile. Are you sure the standard allows it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's what my question about.

Comment: Your question asks something different, whether it’s allowed to add ...

Comment: @Dani yep. Now I see the difference. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat despite the standard conformance (if any), code like ´std::initializer_list l{1,2,3};´ I think it should be expected as valid for regular c++ developer. So if there is lack in standard then standard should be fixed.

Comment: This is a Clang bug, not a problem in the standard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63426926/5632316

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a deduction guide to a standard library type is UB [[namespace std]§4.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/namespace.std#4.4):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares : [...]

> - a deduction guide for any standard library class template.